# enable button to submit only when all the fields are filled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I have a form which has 3 field. First two fields are email_from and email_subject and the last field is an editor. I have used draftjs for editor. If there is no editor i could enable and disable the submit button but due to the inclusion of the editor i did not know how can i enable the button only when all the fields are filled with no error.

Here is my code.

AdminEditor is the component which has draftjs editor

```
class EmailTemplate extends React.Component {
  state = {
    emailSubject: '',
    emailFrom: ''
  };

  handleChange = event =>
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    const { emailSubject, emailFrom } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FieldGroup
          id="formControlsText"
          name="emailSubject"
          type="text"
          label="Email Subject"
          placeholder="Enter Email Form"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          validationState={emailSubject ? 'success' : 'error'}
          required
        />
        <FieldGroup
          id="formControlsText"
          name="emailFrom"
          type="email"
          label="Email From"
          placeholder="Enter Email From"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          validationState={emailFrom ? 'success' : 'error'}
          required
        />
        <AdminEditor />
        <Button type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default EmailTemplate;

class AdminEditor extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
      isEmpty: true
    };
  }

  onEditorStateChange = editorState => {
    this.setState({
      editorState
    });
  };

  onEditorChange = editorContent => {
    this.setState({
      editorContent
    });
  };

  handleChange = event =>
    this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().hasText()
      ? this.setState({ isEmpty: false })
      : this.setState({ isEmpty: true });

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor
          editorState={this.state.editorState}
          initialContentState={rawContentState}
          toolbarClassName="home-toolbar"
          wrapperClassName="home-wrapper"
          editorClassName="home-editor"
          onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
          toolbar={{
            textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
          }}
          onContentStateChange={this.onEditorChange}
          placeholder="write text here..."
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdminEditor;
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, mostly based around passing some callbacks down into the controlled component which updates the state in the parent.
A simple way would be to pass a handler that sets a flag if the editor is empty or not:

```
class AdminEditor extends React.PureComponent {

...

  handleChange = event =>
    this.props.setEditorIsEmpty(
      this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().hasText()
    );
```

Then in `EmailTemplate`:

```
setEditorIsEmpty(editorIsEmpty) {
  this.setState({
    editorIsEmpty
  });
}

render() {
  const { emailSubject, emailFrom } = this.state;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

      ...

      <AdminEditor
        setEditorIsEmpty={this.setEditorIsEmpty}
      />
      <Button
        type="submit"
        disabled={!emailSubject || !emailFrom || editorIsEmpty}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it.

Comment: if i pass the props editorIsEmpty to AdminEditor and then check if its true show the error then the error will be shown from the start of render but i want error to show when user clicks on the textarea. {editorIsEmpty && 'show error'}

Comment: One way to do this is `onFocus` (or maybe better in `onBlur`), is set a state variable inside the `AdminEditor`, like `touched: true`. Then in the handle change it would be `this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().hasText() && this.state.touched`. Let me know if you need more info and I can add it to the answer with better formatting.

Comment: I initialized the state of touched as false and then applied onBlur event to set the touched flag as true and then changed my handleChange function to this `handleBlur = () => this.setState({ touched: true });`

  `handleChange = event => {
    this.props.setEditorState(
      this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().hasText() && this.state.touched
    );
  };` but it still shows error message at start.

Comment: Sorry i did not check for this.state.touched when displaying error inside render. Its working now. Thanks for your help